# Changing a structure from inside of a function

Tags: c, struct

Im suppose to print student details from the user into a student structure and I don't understand why when I compile with linux terminal, there is no entry or output. Please hep me, I'm new here.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct student 
{
char *name;               

int id;                   

char enroll;             

};

int main()
{
struct student john;
john.name = "John Smith";
john.id = 12345678;
john.enroll = 'D'; 

}

void getStudent(struct student *john)
{

printf("Type the name of the student: ");
john->name = malloc(100);   

fgets(john->name, 100, stdin);

printf("\nType the student number: ");
scanf("%d", &(john->id));

printf("\nType the student enrollment option (D or X): ");
scanf("%c", &(john->enroll)); 
return;
}

void printstudent(struct student john)
{

printf("Student name: %s\n", john.name);

printf("Student number: %d\n", john.id);

printf("Student enrollment option: %c\n", john.enroll);

return;

}
```

Comment: you are not calling the functions anywhere.. call them from `main()` using appropriate parameters..

Comment: you are not calling getStudent or PrintStudent functions from main

Comment: and change to `scanf(" %c", &(john->enroll));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call your functions from main (or from any function that needs them). Writing a function (declaring it) doesn't actually execute it.

```
int main()
{
    foo();   // execute foo (call it)
}

void foo()
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Your functions are functions like printf() and scanf() and have to also be called to be used.

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke the functions you have defined, from the main.
Add this statement inside the `main` function.

```
printstudent(john);
```

Comment: thanks for your response. Did you mean                              int main()
{
printstudent(john);
struct student john;
john.name = "John Smith";
john.id = 12345678;
john.enroll = 'D'; 

 
}